# Ptolemy physic astronomy

Tags: astronomy, earth

in Claudius Ptolemy physic of universe did earth is sphere or Flat ؟

did earth orbit around itself or it is stable?

why he think star have impact on human life ?

Comment: This question might be a better fit on [hsm.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many ancient philosophers such as Aristotle and others, including Ptolemy, the earth was spherical (he was the one who applied longitude and latitude based on a globe to the mapping of earth). That sphere was static and all else revolved around it. He did believe astrology was a science (of his era), it was accepted and well regarded, although his book on the subject does not go into how a person born in a particular date would be or how his life would turn out. He more or less limits his study to describe how planets move and so on. Later others made interpretations and added more magic to it. A final word, if earth is at the center and the moon and sun have influence on earth the other spheres (planets and stars) should do as well... that could be a rationale for him, since astrology was a science and astronomers were expected to be astrologers too. Check

Content/techdigest/pdf/V03-N01/03-01-Newton.pdf